# python remove <span class="searchmatch">

Tags: python

My code is shown here:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
        
    
    S = requests.Session()

    urla = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

    ara = "elon musk"

    bilgi = {
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "list": "search",
        "srsearch": ara
    }
    
    R = S.get(url=urla, params=bilgi)
    DATA = R.json()
    
    html = DATA["query"]["search"][0]["snippet"]
    print("html")

except (ValueError,IndexError):
    print("this value isnt on the wikipedia")
```

When I run the code, I get the following result:

```
<span class="searchmatch">Namık</span> <span class="searchmatch">Kemal</span> (21 December 1840 – 2 December 1888) was an Ottoman democrat, writer, intellectual, reformer, journalist, playwright, and political activist
```

How can I remove all `<span class="searchmatch">Namik</span>`'s here and make it just write the information?

Comment: Regarding your question, I think that's why you're looking at using BeautifulSoup. Give a shot at learning that first with some examples online or via their docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. 

If that isn't enough and you're still stuck, then I would post here again.

Comment: but isnt help me this can you say how can ı

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` by `>` and can grab the last index because the `type` of html variable in your code is `string`.

Add these lines below this one `html = DATA["query"]["search"][0]["snippet"]`

```
html = html.split('>')[-1]
print(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this simple task, you can use `r`egular `e`xpressions.

If you want to remove the search matches:

```
import re
print(re.sub("\<span class=\"searchmatch\">.*</span>", r"",  html))
```

This outputs "(21 December 1840 – 2 December 1888) was an Ottoman democrat, writer, intellectual, reformer, journalist, playwright, and political activist".

---

If you want to replace the search matches with its corresponding words:

```py
import re
print(re.sub("\<span class=\"searchmatch\">(.*?)</span>", r"\1", html))
```

This outputs "Namık Kemal (21 December 1840 – 2 December 1888) was an Ottoman democrat, writer, intellectual, reformer, journalist, playwright, and political activist".